# How to impute country to a global population grid?

Tags: latitude-longitude, grids-graticules, population

Have following gridded population data (available from the History Database of the Global Environment, HYDE)
ftp://ftp.pbl.nl/../hyde/hyde3.1/hyde31_final/1980ad_pop.zip

It looks like this:

ncols   4320
nrows   2160
xllcorner   -180
yllcorner   -90
cellsize    0.0833333
nodata_value    -9999
-9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999
-9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999
-9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999
-9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999
-9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999
-9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999
-9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999
-9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999
-9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999
-9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999
-9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999
-9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999   -9999

Summing up:

- Grids start from -90 latitude and -180 longitude and cover the entire world.
- -9999 denotes an empty grid cell or uninhabited area.
- Positive integers indicate the number of inhabitants in that grid cell.

**I want to use these data to create a database with country as an identifier.** The purpose is to construct something similar to the "Administrative Unit Center Points with Population Estimates" available in "Gridded Population of the World (GPW), v4" 
https://sedac.ciesin.columbia.edu/data/set/gpw-v4-admin-unit-center-points-population-estimates-rev11/metadata
In that database, each country is represented by several (sometimes hundreds of) administrative units. Below example is 8 administrative units from Austria:

COUNTRYNM       NAME1           NAME2       NAME3           CENTROID_X  CENTROID_Y  UN_2000_E

Austria Burgenland  Mittelburgenland    Oberpullendorf  Kaisersdorf     16.38512988 47.53693633 523

Austria Burgenland  Mittelburgenland    Oberpullendorf  Nikitsch        16.64790172 47.52716896 1585

Austria Burgenland  Mittelburgenland    Oberpullendorf  Unterfrauenhaid     16.49435799 47.56207975 773

Austria Burgenland  Nordburgenland      Eisenstadt  Leithaprodersdorf   16.49415522 47.92470064 1190

Austria Burgenland  Nordburgenland      Eisenstadt  Oslip           16.60758297 47.84242217 1336

Austria Burgenland  Nordburgenland      Mattersburg Loipersbach im B~   16.47012631 47.70209712 1279

Austria Burgenland  Nordburgenland      Neusiedl am See Antau           16.48452882 47.77712371 757

Austria Burgenland  Nordburgenland      Oberpullendorf  Zurndorf        16.99868205 47.97553402 1999

CENTROID X and Y are the geographic coordinates (longitude and latitude, respectively). UN_2000_E is the UN WPP-adjusted population estimate for year 2000.

The problem is that **these data are not available for years pre-1990**. (An earlier version GPW v3 includes population data for 1990 and '95, not GPW v4 from which the above is sourced.)

**However, detailed population data ARE available for pre-1990 in the History Database of the Global Environment (HYDE) -- but without any country identifier**. My year of interest is 1980 but there's data for a series of other years as well. The purpose of the operation is to calculate population-weighted country centers (these are different from geographic centers) pre-1990.

Have no idea how to construct a detailed country population database for a pre-1990 period. To simplify, I don't need within-country nominal data, i.e., the data don't have to be identical with the structure of GPW v3 or v4 in which each administrative unit is identified by its name. I am not even interested in administrative units -- but I DO NEED detailed country population data in the sense that

- each country is represented by several units;
- these units are the grid cells from HYDE;
- and each unit is identified by longitude and latitude plus the corresponding population data (number of inhabitants).

That's all I need.

One potential issue I see is that sometimes boundaries crosscut grid cells -- in which case one cannot be sure whether the figure in that very cell pertains to this or that country. Or maybe I'm wrong and this is not an issue.

A much welcome shortcut would be a database that includes population data by administrative centers (or any other breakdown that makes sense, e.g., grid cells) identified by long & lat data for countries. But, apparently, no such database exists pre-1990: https://www.popgrid.org/data-docs-table1 So one has to construct it from the raw gridded ("unidentified") population data.